# Which is correct "a car which" or "a car whose" ?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Which of the sentence is correct grammatically below?

> 1. I have bought a car **which** left door is broken.
> 2. I have bought a car **whose** left door is broken.

Comment: Which one do you think is correct?

Comment: I think either sentence is correct but still I want to be sure.

Comment: The genitive pronoun "whose" is required, so only 2. is correct.

Comment: Or you might say: I have bought a car, the left door of which is broken. But this is a more formal construction and few people would use it in conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Only #2 is correct. "**whose**" can be used with objects and beings.

- I found a book whose pages were made of skin.

However, it isn't the best way to say it and better rephrase the sentences.

- I found a book with pages made of skin.
- I found a book with its pages made of skin.

With your example:

- I have bought a car with a broken left door.
- I have bought a car with its left door broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second sentence is more likely to be grammatically correct than the first one; because "**whose**" defines some sort of ownership, but “**which**” by itself doesn’t. “which” gives additional specification to determine exactly what you’re talking about. However, you can write it :

> I have bought a car, the left door of which is broken.

Answer (score -2):

There are varieties of English in which 1) is grammatical; but as far as I know, in all standard varieties only 2) is grammatical.

Comment: From what I know, option number one is incorrect English.

Comment: I don't do "correct" and "incorrect". I have said only 2) is grammatical in standard varieties of English.